# Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to replace an element many different ways but to no avail. `.write` is no good, `innerHTML` only replaces content but I want to replace the whole element. This method seemed the most simply yet I can't figure out what is wrong this time. When I press the button it gives the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': 2
>   arguments required, but only 1 present.

Aren't the newChild and oldChild the 2 arguments?

HTML

```
    <div id="derp" onclick="replace()">
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </div>
```

Javscript

```
var oldChild = document.getElementById("derp");
var newChild = document.createElement("div");

function replace() {
oldChild.parentNode.replaceChild("newChild, oldChild.firstChild");
}
```

When the oldChild gets replaced is it possible to replace it with a code block in a variable like this?

```
var content1 = '<section id="section1" class="sections">' +
                   "<h1>Block 1</h1> " +
                   "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>" +
                   "<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.</p>" +
                   "<p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>"+
                "</section>";
```

If someone were to help me further, I would be grateful.

Comment: you might want to try `oldChild.parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild.firstChild);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
oldChild.parentNode.replaceChild("newChild, oldChild.firstChild");
```

when you put both these arguments inside quotes, they are considered as a single argument.

You might want to remvoe the quotes and try

```
oldChild.parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild.firstChild);
```

TO replace the existing child `DIV`, you first need to add some `id` to the existing child div. Rewrite the HTML like

```
<div id="derp" onclick="replace()">
    <div id="child">TODO write content</div>
</div>
```

and then

```
var newChild  = document.createElement("newChild");

var oldChild = document.getElementById("child");
var parentDiv = oldChild.parentNode;

function replace() 
{
    parentDiv.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
}
```

But this will work only once. The next time you try to replace it, nothing will happen as the element with id `child` has already been replaced with a new element with id `newChild`. So you might have to come up with some way of managing the element id's.

Refer this for more information: [Node.replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. I removed it and the .parentNode but now it only adds a new div inside the DIV#derp, it doesnt replace/remove the <div>TODO write content</div>. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, done some research on how nodes work and what nodes are. I now understand the logic of your answer and want to say thank you for your time :)